# How can I use a string list from a select statement in a NOT IN clause

Tags: sql-server, select, dynamic, declare

I want to build a list of Lastnames to filter out from the results of the second select statement something like this (which doesn't do it)

```
DECLARE @ExcludedList VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ExcludedList = (SELECT  TOP 20 Lastname
FROM dbo.Subscribers
where [Firstname] = 'Dave')

SELECT [Firstname], Count([Firstname]) as [Count] from Subscribers
WHERE [Lastname] not in (@ExcludedList)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use a variable, then it has to be a *table* variable:

```
DECLARE @ExcludedList TABLE (Lastname VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @ExcludedList
SELECT  TOP 20 Lastname
FROM dbo.Subscribers
WHERE [Firstname] = 'Dave'

SELECT [Firstname], Count([Firstname]) AS [Count] 
FROM Subscribers
WHERE [Lastname] NOT IN (SELECT Lastname FROM @ExcludedList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do it directly like

```
SELECT [Firstname], Count([Firstname]) as [Count] from Subscribers
WHERE [Lastname] not in (SELECT  TOP 20 Lastname
FROM dbo.Subscribers where [Firstname] = 'Dave')
```

Well I am not sure what you are actually trying to achieve but consider using a `table variable` and use like below

```
DECLARE @ExcludedList table(lastname varchar(30));
insert into @ExcludedList
SELECT  TOP 20 Lastname
FROM dbo.Subscribers where [Firstname] = 'Dave';

SELECT [Firstname], Count([Firstname]) as [Count] from Subscribers
WHERE [Lastname] not in (select lastname from @ExcludedList);
```

Comment: Thats not the actual query I'm using its more complicated but I wanted to put something up to illustrate the question. I was using something like that but it was very slow

Comment: Then try posting the actual problem you are trying to solve. Anyways, see edit in answer if that helps. You can try using a table variable as well in this case.